# Vergleiche: Verb ans Ende oder in die Mitte?

Tags: usage, grammaticality, comparison

Man betrachte folgende Vergleichssätze, in denen die Verben am Ende stehen:

> Das trifft auf jeden zu, der es mindestens so gut wie du kann.

> Das sind diejenigen, die es besser als du können.

> Also jeder, der mindestens so klug wie du ist.

M. E. *könnte* man zwar auch schreiben (und tut es auch oft):

> Das trifft auf jeden zu, der es mindestens so gut kann wie du.

> Das sind die, die es besser können als du.

> Also jeder, der mindestens so klug ist wie du.

...aber man sollte die Verben lieber ans Ende stellen, vor allem schriftlich, auch wenn sie umgangssprachlich üblicherweise in die Mitte gestellt werden.

Stimmt's?

Comment: Mit "man sollte" meine ich, dass zwar beides grammatikalisch korrekt ist (meine Vermutung), aber die erste Variante "besseres" Deutsch ist (ebenso nur meine Vermutung).

Comment: Ich denke nicht, daß das Phänomen irgendwas mit *Vergleichen* zu tun hat. Bei manchen Nebensätzen kann halt die Verbletztstellung verlassen werden, wie in "Es gibt Leute, die waren halt noch nie in New York"

Comment: Ich habe dafür gestimmt, diese Frage zu schließen, weil *... aber man sollte ... Stimmt's?* geradezu als Definition für *opinion based* gelten könnte.

Comment: Die bestehende Antwort nimmt an, dass die Varianten nur stilistische Unterschiede aufweisen -- [nicht unbedingt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informationsstruktur).

Comment: @tofro Ich weiß nicht, ob der Satz korrekt wäre. “Es gibt Leute, die halt noch nie in New York waren” oder??

Comment: Natürlich ist der Satz (auch) korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage stellt explizit eine *normative* Frage und fragt nach der stilistischen "Richtigkeit" der beiden Formulierungen. Was ein *angemessener* Stil ist, kann je nach Textsorte, Sprecherintention und Adressat verschieden sein. Die Vorstellungen von stilistischer Angemessenheit entstehen interaktiv, werden diskursiv verhandelt, und sind dabei oft implizit und nur in Ausnahmefällen kodifiziert - etwa in "Style Guides" für bestimmte Textsorten, etwa für Arbeiten im akademischen Betrieb oder auch entsprechende Richtlinien von Zeitungen für ihre Journalisten.

Die normativen Vorstellungen über Sprache sind sehr stark von Autoritäts- und Konventionalitätsargumenten geprägt. Dissens darüber lässt sich nicht restlos mit beschreibenden Methoden auflösen oder klären, und es bleibt immer ein subjektives Moment übrig. Die Akzeptanz bestimmter Autoritäten ist, gerade was Stil angeht, eine Eigenschaft des sozialen Habitus; die stilistische Angemessenheit bestimmter Ausdrücke kann daher gerade je nach sozialem Kontext variieren.

Aus meiner *persönlichen* Erfahrung kann ich nur sagen, dass mir die ersten Varianten noch niemals über den Weg gelaufen sind, weder in der mündlichen Umgangssprache, noch in schriftlichen Texten, auch in "hochsprachlichen" Texten, also in Texten anerkannter Autoren der Belletristrik oder in akademischen Texten nicht. Daher würde ich sagen, dass diese Wortreihenfolge nicht verbreitet ist.

Ich halte die *allgemeine* Regel "Verben sollten ans Satzende gestellt werden" nicht für verbreitet oder auch in dieser Allgemeinheit für sinnvoll, denn die Wortreihenfolge kann ja semantische und emphatische Nuancen tragen.

Im hier vorliegenden *konkreten* Fall glaube ich überdies, dass die Regel zu Redeweisen führen würde, deren Stil in jedem Fall auffällig wäre. Stilistische Auffälligkeiten, die nicht von einer erkennbaren Bedeutungsvariation motiviert sind, sind besonders auffällig und in meinen Augen Anzeichen für schlechten Stil. Das würde hier in meinen Augen zutreffen. Ich würde diese Ausdrucksweise für gestelzt halten; die syntaktische Nähe zu entsprechenden englischen Sätzen (etwa: *That holds true for anyone who can do it at least as good as you can*) würde mich vermuten lassen, dass ich es mit einem nichtmuttersprachlichen Sprecher zu tun habe.

Das ist allerdings nicht zu verwechseln mit der syntaktischen Regel, dass das finite Verb im Nebensatz an letzter Stelle steht. Das ist ja aber nicht die Regel, nach der gefragt wurde.

Comment: Für Nebensätze der Art, wie sie in der Frage als Beispiele präsentiert werden, gilt allerdings in der Tat die generelle Regel, dass das Verb am Ende steht. Da könnte man tatsächlich auf die Idee kommen, dass auch da das Verb ans Ende gestellt werden soll. Allerdings hat sich die Praxis, das Verb bei Vergleichen nach vorne zu ziehen, so weit etabliert, dass es mir zweifelhaft erscheint, dagegen ankämpfen zu wollen.

Comment: "Für Nebensätze der Art, wie sie in der Frage als Beispiele präsentiert werden, gilt allerdings in der Tat die generelle Regel, dass das Verb am Ende steht." Jonathan scheint ja davon abzuraten. Wer von euch beiden hat denn nun recht :)

Comment: Genau da liegt das Problem: es gibt keine Vorschriften, und was besser gefällt hängt von Kontext und Person ab... mir ist ebenfalls eher die erste Form geläufig... ein „Recht haben“ gibt es hier nicht

Comment: Eine feste Regel, nach der das Verb an das Ende des Nebensatzes, den man so formulieren, wie es sich nach besagter Regel, die hier diskutiert wird, ergibt, möchte, gehört, erschwert manchmal das Verständnis

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Nein, wieso? :D

Comment: @weltschmerz Na, ich. Sag ich doch.